# phpmyadmin: how to remove time limit to import big databases

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

how can I remove the time limit for the import operation in phpmyadmin ?

I'm not able to upload a big database because of the limit and I have to login again in the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use MySQL [BigDump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump.php)

Worked well for me yesterday!

Comment: I think it worked great. I'm only a bit scared about 1 thing: I've exported (downloaded) the new database to see if it has the same size of the original one. Well, it is 15.4 instead of 15.5 (I think it is ok, but shouldn't it be exactly the same number ? (On the same operating system and size field) ?

Comment: Did you get any error messages using BigDump when you executed the script? If you didn't, it should not be a problem.

Comment: No problem, post here if you have any problems with it!

Answer (score 4):

you must open config.inc.php file in phpmyadmin root folder.
add this line:

```
$cfg["ExecTimeLimit"]=36000;
```

adjusted the time limit will be 10 hours.

if you want to set an infinity time for timelimit you can use this

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't use phpmyadmin to upload big databases... use console mysql/mysqldump.

but you can chenge max_execution_time parameter in your php.ini if you really want to

Answer (score 1):

Try out [mysqldumper](http://www.mysqldumper.net/)