# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded / putty / plesk

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, putty

i have a large sql database every time i try to upload it i get

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded
```

I changed all possible php setting upload size time memory but no result. After a few hours i understand that i should change config.inc.php in myphp
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300 to a large number 9999 or 0 but the problem i'm beginner, i use plesk but no way to change it using interface
i installed putty now i'm logged to it but no idea how to do it.

I have centOS 6.6 and plesk 12
please i began you help me but sample syntax that i can paste it to putty thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371047/phpmyadmin-how-to-remove-time-limit-to-import-big-databases

Comment: yes already read it but he don't explain how to edit config.inc.php

Answer (score 0):

i didn't found a response to my question :( but here is a simple tool that can help you to import big sql data
http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/
it's very simple, tutoriel in the same page