# PHPMyAdmin script timeout, Wampserver64

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I'm currently local hosting with Wampserver64(latest) and am attempting to import a database for a future merge.
Altho upon uploading the .sql, it runs smoothly for about a minute or two, before it ends with the following error:
**Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit the same file and import will resume.** (resubmitting does not continue, it starts over.)
I've looked around for a solution and was told to set libraries/config.default.php $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] to 0, but with no success.
Might have been that those were Mamp or Xamp answers.
If anyone would happen to know how to fix this, please let me know, it would be really helpful :)

Comment: just import it on cmd line... `mysql –u[user name] -p[password] [database name] < C:\[filename].sql`

Comment: Not too familiar with the command line of PMA, so I had no idea, thanks mate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set my phpmyadmin user session to not time out so quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886740/how-to-set-my-phpmyadmin-user-session-to-not-time-out-so-quickly)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371047/phpmyadmin-how-to-remove-time-limit-to-import-big-databases